# Rstudio formatting help for graphing

Tags: r

```
data$variable.n <- read.table(data$variable header=TRUE, text=" 
Pipette  Volume  Before  After
100  10  1.833  1.844
100  30  1.844  1.864
100  45  1.864  1.878
100  55  1.878  1.883
100  80  1.883  1.914
100  99  1.914  1.929")
pipetteframe$Mass <- pipetteframe$After - pipetteframe$Before
biglm <- lm(Mass ~ Volume, data=pipetteframe, subset=(Pipette=="1000H"))
summary(biglm)
littlelm <- lm(Mass ~ Volume, data=pipetteframe, subset=(Pipette=="100C"))
summary(littlelm)
```

What did I do wrong in this code block that prevents it from graphing? When I try to knit this, I get an error on the second line at "header=True". I'm not sure how to fix this, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're missing a comma before `header=TRUE`, but also, I don't understand what you mean when you have `data$variable` as the first argument of `data.table()`.